# How to find degree of a polynomial equation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, equation, polynomial-math

I want to find the degree of polynomial equation

```
den = a^2+a+1
```

The output of equation should be

```
2
```

or

```
den=a^2+a^3+a+1
```

The output of the equation should be

```
3
```

But I am unable to find the correct solution for JavaScript

Comment: `^` is not an exponential operator here. It is bit wise `XOR` in Js

Comment: Is the right side of equation a string ?

Comment: yes it is string

Comment: @GeorgeBailey i have to take a^2+a^3+a+1 as input in js and give 2 as output as it is the highest degree of equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regexp to get all the exponents and calculate the maximum

```js
var r = /a(\^\d)?/g;
var t = 'a^2+a^3+a+1';

var order = t.match(r).reduce((m, d) => {
 var ex = d.split('^')[1];
 if(ex && (ex > m)){
  return ex;
 }
 return m;
},0);

console.log(order); // Logs '3'
```

You can also do the same without using `Array.prototype.reduce` (have used a simple for loop and avoided ES6 syntax for simplicity)

```js
var r = /a(\^\d)?/g;
var t = 'a^2+a^3+a+1';

var order = 0;

var matches = t.match(r);

for(var i = 0, j = matches.length ; i< j; i++){
  var exp = matches[i].split('^')[1];
  if(exp && (exp > order)){
    order = exp;
  }
}

console.log(order); // Logs '3'
```